# android temporary activity.MAIN to set preferences

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have an activity to set my preferences the first time that application get opened, but how can I change activity status (move the "MAIN" on another activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot move the MAIN Activity to another activity at runtime. It is mandatory to define it while writing Manifest file. If you want to do that as per preferences values then check the preference value everytime and then move to your required activity.

Open `SplashScreenActivity`--> check preference value here-->If false go to your `FirstActivity` when app launched newly-->If true go to your `AnotherActivity`.

Hope you got the concept.